# Question about null coalescing operator (??) and rendering twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some question about null coalescing operator (??) to rendering a twig view. So I would like to set the form to null if the user is not logged. I give you my PHP controller method code :

```php
    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_recipe_show', methods: ['GET', 'POST'], requirements: ['id' => '[1-9]\d*'])]
    public function show(Recipe $recipe, UserRepository $userRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        // If the user is logged
        if ($user) {
            // If the user is the cooker of the recipe
            $isCooker = $user->getId() === $recipe->getCooker()->getId();

            // If the recipe is in the user's favorites
            $isFavorite = $user->getFavorites() !== null && in_array($recipe->getId(), $user->getFavorites(), true);

            // create form to add/remove the recipe to the user's favorites
            $favoriteForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => ($isFavorite) ? 'Remove from favorites' : 'Add to favorites'])
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->getForm();

            $favoriteForm->handleRequest($request);

            if ($favoriteForm->isSubmitted() && $favoriteForm->isValid()) {
                if ($isFavorite) {
                    // remove the recipe from the user's favorites
                    $user->removeRecipeFromFavorites($recipe->getId());
                } else {
                    // add the recipe to the user's favorites
                    $user->addRecipeToFavorites($recipe->getId());
                }
                // persist the user and flush it
                $userRepository->add($user, true);
                // redirect to the recipe show page
                return $this->redirectToRoute(
                    'app_recipe_show',
                    ['id' => $recipe->getId()],
                    Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->render('recipe/show.html.twig', [
            'recipe' => $recipe,
            'is_cooker' => $isCooker ?? false,
            'is_favorite' => $isFavorite ?? false,
            // null coalescing operator (??) set the form to null if the user is not logged
            'favorite_form' => $favoriteForm->createView() ?? null,
        ]);
    }
```

And I have an error telling that the variable $favoriteForm is Undefined. What's normal ! How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that behaviour is normal. That's because `??` is evaluating the result of `createView()`, but it cannot be executed because `$favoriteForm` isn't defined: it's created conditionally only if there's a user logged in.

If you are using php >= 8.0, you'd want to use the [nullsafe operator](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator) instead:

```
'favorite_form' => $favoriteForm?->createView(),
```

If you are in a lower version, you'd have to resort to a more terse construct:

```
'favorite_form' => isset($favoriteForm) ? $favoriteForm->createView() : null,
```

Also, as it's used it doesn't make much sense, because according to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

> The null coalescing operator (??) [...] returns its first operand if it exists and is not null;
> otherwise it returns its second operand.

If `createView()` returned `null`, coalescing to `null` would be a no-op.